# SharePoint 2010 Custom User Profile Property - An error occurred when updating a property

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I had a custom user profile property "EmployeeId" type of integer that was mapped to an AD attribute.  I deleted this and recreated the property with the same name and integer type but this time I mapped to a BDC property.  When I click OK I get the error 'An error occurred when updating a property'.  I can successfully add new properties mapped to a BDC property.

I restarted the following but still get this error:

User Profile Service
User Profile Synchronization Service

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the custom user profile property was originally string multivalue type.  When I deleted it and recreated I selected integer as the type.  For some reason this caused a conflict.  After changing the type back to string multivalue the problem is gone.